# Regular expression about numeric and other spices

Tags: regex

I would like to create a regular expression in "php" which check whether a string made of numbers ":" " " "," "\carriage return" I know it is something simple but I'm a little green in this field. thanks in advance .

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Try writing something yourself and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.* )(?=.*:)(?=.*,)(?=.*\r)[: \d,\r]+$/
```

`^` is the start of string

`.` matches any single character

`.*` matches 0 to many characters(`.`)

`(?=.*\d)` is a lookahead which would match further only if it has a digit..

`[abcd]` is a charactes class which would match a OR b OR c OR d

`$` is the end of the string

Comment: thanks but , get "Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found mistake

Comment: @user1823410 you have not used delimiter `/` at start and end..check out the edit

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use PHP's `is_numeric()` method?

[View is_numeric in PHP Documentation](http://php.net/is_numeric)

Comment: that my be correct ,  but i have some characters as ":" or "\n" "," which are not numeric

Comment: Oh right, sorry, your question wasn't that clear - maybe stick some examples of the kind of things you have to validate